# How to create bigger time period from multiple smaller ones?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing time periods

```
StartDate               CancelDate
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000
2014-01-16 00:00:00.000 2014-01-31 00:00:00.000
2014-02-05 00:00:00.000 2014-02-15 00:00:00.000
```

You can see that periods in first two rows are connected and a they are creating one bigger period from `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-31`, and there is a period that is not connected in third row.

How can I get this table from the one above?

```
    StartDate               CancelDate
    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-01-31 00:00:00.000
    2014-02-05 00:00:00.000 2014-02-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: They're not connected, there's a 24 hour gap between the first and second row.

Comment: They should be treated as connected, time part in datetime is not important

Comment: Can you have multiple overlaps?

Comment: Still not connected. "No time part" just means "midnight." So the first row ends at midnight of the 15th and the second row starts on midnight of the 16th. You can't interpret the same data as having different values in different columns. That is, StartDate as "midnight of the date shown" and CancelDate as "one tick before midnight of the day after the date shown." This may sound like nit-picking, but you open yourself up to a lot of trouble when you start doing that. Which is why you came here....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something on these lines should work:

```
SELECT MIN(startdate) StartDate, CancelDate
FROM
(
SELECT a.startdate, 
COALESCE(b.canceldate, a.canceldate) canceldate
FROM dt a
LEFT JOIN dt b ON
(b.startdate=DATEADD(d,1,a.canceldate) OR a.canceldate=b.startdate)
) x
GROUP BY CancelDate
```

dt is your data table

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (start VARCHAR(10),enddate VARCHAR(10))
insert into @t (start,enddate)values
('2014-01-01','2014-01-15'),
('2012-01-01','2012-01-15'),
('2014-01-15','2014-01-31'),
('2014-02-02','2014-02-15'),
('2014-02-15','2014-02-28')

Select MIN(CAST (start AS DATE)),MAX(CAST (enddate AS DATE)) 
from @t 
group by LEFT(start,7),LEFT(enddate,7)
```

OR Using CTE

```
   ;WITH CTE AS 
(
select DISTINCT

    (select min(start) from @t
        where LEFT(start,7) = LEFT(m.start,7)
        ) as StartDate,
    (select max(enddate) from @t
        where LEFT(enddate,7) = LEFT(m.enddate,7)
        ) as EndDate,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(STart,7) ORDER BY  LEFT(STart,7) DESC)RN 
from
    @t m
    )
    Select DISTINCT StartDate,EndDate from CTE
```